# C++: How Can I keep my program (output console) alive

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program (my 1st program) to display the laptop battery, however, I would like to keep it active to monitor the battery %.:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

id:
SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS spsPwr;
if (GetSystemPowerStatus(&spsPwr)) {
    cout << "\nAC Status : " << static_cast<double>(spsPwr.ACLineStatus)
        << "\nBattery Status : " << static_cast<double>(spsPwr.BatteryFlag)
        << "\nBattery Life % : " << static_cast<double>(spsPwr.BatteryLifePercent)
        << endl;
    system("CLS");
    goto id;
    return 0;
}
else return 1;
```

}

using goto seems to be a bad idea as the CPU utilization jump to 99% ! :(, I am sure this is not the right way to do it.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: `Sleep()` for 10 seconds (or however long) after each time you check. The process won't use CPU while it's sleeping.

Comment: add a thread sleep period (delay) in the loop. also use a `for(;;)` infinite loop instead of that `goto`. and don't return 1 to indicate failure, return `EXIT_FAILURE` from `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the issue you are asking about: of course you get 100% CPU usage, since you're asking the computer to try and get and print the power status of the computer as fast it possibly can. And since computers will happily do what you tell them to, well... you know what happens next.

As others have said, the solution is to use an API that will instruct your application to go to sleep. In Windows, which appears to be your platform of choice, that API is [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
// Sleep for around 1000 milliseconds - it may be slightly more since Windows
// is not a hard real-time operating system.
Sleep(1000);
```

Second, please do not use `goto`. There are looping constructs in C and you should use them. I'm not fundamentally opposed to `goto` (in fact, in my kernel-driver programming days I used it quite frequently) but I am opposed to seeing it used when better alternatives are available. In this case the better alternative is a `while` loop.

Before I show you that let me point out another issue: **DO NOT USE THE `system` function**.

Why? The `system` function executes the command passed to it; on Windows it happens to execute inside the context of the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) which supports and internal command called `cls` which happens to clear the screen. At least on *your* system. But yours isn't the only system in the world. On some other system, there might be a program called `cls.exe` which would get executed instead, and who knows what that would do? It could clear the screen, or it could format the hard drive. So please, don't use the `system` function. It's almost always the wrong thing to do. If you find yourself looking for that command stop and think about what you're doing and whether you need to do it.

So, you may ask, how do I clear the screen if I can't use `system("cls")`? There's a way to do it which *should* be portable across various operating systems:

```
int main(int, char **)
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS spsPwr;

    while (GetSystemPowerStatus(&spsPwr)) 
    {
        std::string status = "unknown";

        if (spsPwr.ACLineStatus == 0)
            status = "offline";
        else if (spsPwr.ACLineStatus == 1)
            status = "online";

        // The percent of battery life left is returned as a value
        // between 0 and 255 so we normalize it by multiplying it
        // by 100.0 and dividing by 255.0 which is ~0.39.

        std::cout << "Current Status: " << status << " (" 
                  << static_cast<int>(spsPwr.BatteryFlag) << "): " 
                  << 0.39 * static_cast<int>(spsPwr.BatteryLifePercent)
                  << "% of battery remaining.\r" << std::flush;

        // Sleep for around 1000 milliseconds - it may be slightly more
        // since Windows is not a hard real-time operating system.
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    // Print a new line before exiting.    
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What this does is print the information in a single line, then move back to the beginning of that line, sleep for around one second and then write the next line, overwriting what was previously there.

If the new line you write is shorter than the previous line, you may see some visual artifacts. Removing them should not be difficult but I'll leave it for you as an exercise. Here's a hint: what happens if you output a space where a letter used to be?

In order to do this across lines, you will need to use more advanced techniques to manipulate the console, and this exercise becomes a lot trickier.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (true) {
   // do the stuff
   ::Sleep(2000);  // suspend thread to 2 sec
}
```

(you are on Windows according to the API function)

see: [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are having 100% CPU usage because your program is always running.

I don't want to get into details, and given that this is your first program, I'll recommend to put a call to `usleep` before the `goto`.

And, of course, avoid `goto`, use a proper loop instead.

```
int milliseconds2wait = 3000;

while (!flag_exit) {
 // code
 usleep( 1000 * milliseconds2wait )
}
```

**Update:** This is windows, use `Sleep` instead of `usleep`:

```
 Sleep( milliseconds2wait );
```